# NUNJUCKS: How to access a variable set inside a macro outside it?

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

I am passing something to a macro and performing some operations on it. I am storing the result in a variable. Now I want to access this variable outside the macro.

Is there a way we can do this?
Example:

```
{% macro setexpression() %}

{% set expression = "Hello World!" %} 

{% endmacro %}
```

> I call the macro and expression should be available outside.

```
{{ setexpression() }}

{{ expression }}  // This should return Hello World!
```

I found a hacky way to do this.

```
{% macro returnSomething() %}
{% set returnVar = "Hello there" %}
{{returnVar}}
{% endmacro %}
```

And then, the calling code will be:

```
{% set returned = returnSomething() %}
{{returned}} // this will have 'Hello there' in it
```

Is there a better way in which I can achieve the same?

Comment: `{% set %}` inside a macro defines a local `var`. It's the expected behaviour in contrast to your. Why do you want it?

Comment: @AikonMogwai I want the macro to return a string (or value) after it's done processing it. In my project, I use that string to render customized UI. I found a hacky solution to this which I'm now including in question. Please do tell if there's an alternate or better way.

Comment: `Global function` looks like a more appropriate to change `var`-value than `macro`.

Comment: That is my last resort. If there is no other alternate way, I'll switch to Global function. I changed my question @AikonMogwai. Do you know of a better way than what I suggested?

Comment: Hmmm, the last way is a little bit strange for me but it's ok :)